# Adding textbox to a pane

Tags: java

I am trying to add a simple textbox to my class of type `JDialog` but it does not seem to work, I don't know what I am doing wrong:

```
    Container pane = getContentPane();      

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    pane.add(panel);
    JTextField userText = new JTextField(20);
    userText.setBounds(100, 10, 160, 25);
    pane.setVisible(true);

    panel.add(userText);
    panel.setLayout(null);
```

Comment: Make use of an appropriate layout manager

Comment: *"I don't know what I am doing wrong:"* - Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: can you share the complete code?

Comment: My code is very large, that's why I didn't post it. The piece of it which is above belongs to a function included in a class of type JDialog, which is called by main. What do you mean by layout manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your actual code is not available,tried to replicate a similar one.
Try to pass the JFrame reference to the superclass and use setSize and setVisible methods to specify the size and make the dialog visible.Try this and check if this works.

```
 class SampleDialog extends JDialog {
/**
 * The constructor creates the window with all the controls.
 * Constructor takes a JFrame object
 */
SampleDialog(JFrame jframe) {
    //pass the parameters to the superclass(JDialog)
    super(jframe,true);
    Container pane = getContentPane();      
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    pane.add(panel);
    JTextField userText = new JTextField(20);
    userText.setBounds(100, 10, 160, 25);
    panel.add(userText);
    WindowEvent we = new WindowEvent(this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSED);
    this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    setSize(200, 200);
    setVisible(true);      
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    SampleDialog sampleDialog = new SampleDialog(new JFrame());
}}
```